# PHP: Post 70 Variables --> Array --> MySQL

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP page with around 70 fields that gets posted.
31 have the following patern: hours_1, hours_2, hours_3 etc..
31 have the following patern: description_1, description_2, description_3 etc..
There are a few other variables/fields like clientID, month, year
As you can see, yes that looks like a timesheet.
It gets posted and therefore I would like to all the hours in one array and the descriptions in another and after that insert it in a table.
How do I get these hour and description fields neatly into an array (or two arrays) so I can, after some validation, use them to insert them into a MySQL table?

Comment: What is the source of those variables? Are they going from external API or it was your design to make those names like that? If it was yours, then it's bad design and you better change it.

Comment: In PHP or HTML, you can always use the [] convention to name or receive your variables into arrays on the server side

Answer (score 0):

In PHP or HTML, you can always use the [] convention to name or receive your variables into arrays on the server side i.e.

Instead of generating the variables with _number as you seem to be doing, you can:

```
<?php foreach(range(0, 30) as $i): ?>
    <input name="hours[]">
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This will allow you to neatly receive as array on server side so you can

```
$_POST['hours'];//will give you an array of all the hour inputs if you submit with post
```